# Book that includes a sections describing a dying world orbiting a red giant, populated by evolved form of algae eating crab

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a science fiction\fantasy book dating to around the late 1970s, early 1980s. Probably English or German.

Part way though the book it takes a sudden short change of direction and instead of describing the main character's journey it describes a dying world orbiting a red dwarf star. It's only a relatively short section as I remember it, but it describes a creature that may or may not be intelligent, but which is a highly evolved form of crab that spends most of its life feeding on algae that grows on the rocky shoreline of a near sterile sea. The impression is that this represents the only remaining habitable part of the world with a functioning ecosystem.

I'm remember that it was a section of another book, and that this sub section didn't really relate to the main plot.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

EDIT: I've never read any HG Wells, so it's probably not the Time Machine

Answer (score 17):

This sounds like *The Time Machine* by H. G. Wells [[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine)].  Towards the end, when the time traveler gets his time machine back, he travels forwards in time until the sun has turned red and spends a brief period in this time without intelligent life.

Some quotes:

> The rocks about me were of a harsh reddish colour, and all the trace of life that I could see at first was the intensely green vegetation that covered every projecting point on their south-eastern face.

> Looking round me again, I saw that, quite near, what I had taken to be a reddish mass of rock was moving slowly towards me.  Then I saw the thing was really a monstrous crab-like creature.  Can you image a crab as large as yonder table, with its many legs moving slowly and uncertainly, its big claws swaying, its long antennae, like carters' whips, waving and feeling, and its stalked eyes gleaming at you on either side of its metallic front?

> I cannot convey the sense of abominable desolation that hung over the world.  The red eastern sky, the northward blackness, the salt Dead Sea, the stony beach crawling with these foul, slow-stirring monsters, the uniform poisonous-looking green of the lichenous plants, the thin air that hurts one's lungs: all contributed to an appalling effect.

Comment: @jwodderm, it sounds very similar, but I've never read and of Well's books, so I'm not sure that this is the one. I also remember the tone being a lot sadder. Maybe it was inspired by this scene?

Comment: @AaarghZombies A lot sadder than *this*? "I cannot convey the sense of abominable desolation that hung over the world." *The Time Machine* is short enough that you might find it in an anthology with stories by other writers.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds just like the Time Machine novel, where the Protagonist went to the year 3 billion and saw the last remnants of life on a Dying Earth. Red crabs scrabbling about under a dying red giant star.

Comment: Adds nothing to the existing answer.

Answer (score -4):

The description matches H G Wells' "The Time Machine" (Chapter 14, "The Further Vision") with such particularity, that if it is not that book, it might be another that plagiarized Wells for whatever strange purpose.

The chapter (like the rest of the book) is available online free of charge on Project Gutenberg.

The late Ursula K Le Guin called Wells' vision of fading Earth the most beautiful nightmare in all of literature.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer has already been suggested.  Please don't post answers that duplicate existing answers